# Visual Studio code with Java environment in Docker Container

Tags: java, docker, visual-studio-code

My question is, if I can run Java and Debug it from within Visual Studio Code. I can edit my code and then start it in a container. But is it also possible to run the docker container, having a volume with the code folder mounted into the container and then configure Visual Studio Code somehow to use Java from the container? I saw there is the .vscode folder with launch.json or settings.json, but I found no way so far to use the run/debug command and use Java from within the Docker container. I was looking for a way to use java 11 without breaking my current config.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option really is to use the [Remote Development extension pack](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) for Visual Studio Code, and then use Docker containers.

See [this sample](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote-tutorials/containers/get-the-sample) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Vscode remote extension doesn't provide any support to debug a java app inside a container, for now.